# Merged cells not preserved when copying and pasting

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I wrote a script to copy and paste a block of cells from one sheet to another in Google Sheets, and everything is working fine except the merged cells are no longer merged after the cells are pasted. I've tried using `CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL` to no avail.

Here's my script:

```
function newRows() {
  // insert new blank rows
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(3,14);

  // copy and paste 
  var source = copySheet.getRange(1,1,14,9);
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(3,1,12,9);
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // add date
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date = new Date();
  var nextDate = new Date();
  var days = 4;
  nextDate.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(nextDate, tz, 'MM/dd/yy');
  var cell = sheet.getRange(4,4);
  cell.setValue("Week Ending " + stringDate);
  
}
```

Here's what I want (merged cells are grey):
[image]

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code but I was able to observe the following:

The `source` and `destination` ranges are of different sizes. `source` has 14 rows while `destination` has 12 rows. Try changing

```
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(3,1,12,9);
```

to

```
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(3,1,14,9);
```